# form validation js of multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to check password inputs in few forms. I don't get any error message but I don't know why it doesn't work. Any ideads how to fix it? Thanks

`Link:`[link](https://jsfiddle.net/e0y3jcha/3/)

Comment: On your addEventListener, what is "blue"?

Comment: @Loaf I meant "blur"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few corrections in js code: see below snippet:

1. `this.passwordInputs.length` to `this.value.length`
2. `var pgMsg = document.querySelector(".form-container p");` to `var pgMsg = document.querySelector(".form-element p");`

```js
var error = "";
var passwordInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=password]');

if (passwordInputs.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < passwordInputs.length; i++) {
        var passwordInputsList = passwordInputs[i];
        passwordInputsList.addEventListener("blur", passwordCheck, false);
    }
}

function passwordCheck() {
    if (this.value.length < 8) {
        error = "Password is too short";
        var pgMsg = document.querySelector(".form-element p");
        pgMsg.textContent = error;
        console.log(pgMsg.textContent);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-element">
    <label for="register-password"></label>
    <img src="img/Icons/password.png" alt="Password Icon">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="register-password" placeholder="Password">
    <p class="pg-valid" id="pg-valid"></p>
</div>

<div class="form-element">
    <label for="register-password-repeat"></label>
    <img src="img/Icons/password.png" alt="Password Icon">
    <input type="password" name="password-repeat" id="register-password-repeat" placeholder="Confirm Password">
</div>

<div class="form-element">
    <label for="signin-password"></label>
    <img src="img/Icons/password.png" alt="Password Icon">
    <input type="password" id="signin-password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Comment: You should check console for any errors, there were few errors which are corrected.

Comment: How to get message under every input?

Comment: I didn't understand how to use "this"

Comment: okay, add `console.log(this)` inside function `passwordCheck()` ? you will understand

Comment: and what about my question?

Comment: How about you go through the code and see how this is added in first input?

Comment: I did actually and I can see what is going on in console. "Password is too short" appears after every blur  with input.